# javascript variable in php code

Tags: javascript, php

Hi guys I'm working with google charts.

I'm using PHP to capture the data i need from a database which is then stored into a incramental varible (month1 , month2, etc.)

Now i need to pass this to javascript when i was using just a set number of months this was fine as i used the code:

```
var month1="<?php echo $month1value; ?>";
```

I created a while loop that starts [i] at 1 and then increases to the number of months used.

I am new to javascript so assumed i would be able to do something like this:

```
var month[i] = "<?php echo $month" + i + "value; ?>";
```

however this doesn't work and i get:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '" + i + "' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ',' or ';'
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Isn't your `i` variable a JavaScript variable? If so I'm sure that is syntactically incorrect. You can't AFAIK use JavaScript like that within PHP code.

Comment: why new variables for each date? `$date = array();` assign each date data to this array and then use this array everywhere(either in php or in javascript)

Comment: If I had it in a php array how could I then make say the first item of the array also be the first item of a JavaScript array?

Comment: @Script47 yes it is a JavaScript variable that's the part I'm stuck on. How can I take a php array and pass value i into a JavaScript array at the same position i?

Comment: @MikeDray pass it to JavaScript to as a cookie from PHP.

Comment: Oh thanks json_encode() is just what I was looking for. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need save data in variable (month1 , month2, etc.).
you can you something like this:

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "var month[i] = " . $row["month"] . ";";
}
echo "</script>";
```

I hope this code help you

Comment: Hi thanks. This would work great i guess I missed a bit from my original question it it not just getting a value from a db it is actually getting several values then finding an average. Or have in misunderstood what $result is?

Comment: $result = mysql_query($query); but if you want to do some work on your data you can save them in an array and at last write a loop on array instead of loop on mysql_fetch_array